# How can I show vertical line in highchart as shown in below image?

Tags: highcharts

How to show vertical line same as cross hair but not of full hight. It should not go beyond plot point as shown in image?

[Verticle chart line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNXID.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Highcharts.SVGRenderer.path` method in the `mouseOver` event, example:

```
    series: [{
        ...,
        point: {
            events: {
                mouseOver: function() {
                    var chart = this.series.chart,
                        x = this.plotX + chart.plotLeft,
                        y1 = this.plotY + chart.plotTop,
                        y2 = chart.plotTop + chart.plotHeight;

                    this.customCrosshair = chart.renderer.path(
                            ['M', x, y1, 'L', x, y2]
                        )
                        .attr({
                            'stroke-width': 2,
                            dashstyle: 'dot',
                            stroke: 'gray'
                        })
                        .add();
                },
                mouseOut: function() {
                    this.customCrosshair.destroy();
                }
            }
        }
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/52d0vj7r/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.point.events

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#path